# Fetch does not return anything

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am making a post request with fetch and looking for response to come back to use it on my page.
I have a code like this:

```
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = {name: document.querySelector('input[name = "name"]').value, age: document.querySelector('input[name="age"]').value}
  fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => console.log(data));
  
})
```

Data goes to backend okay, but fetch does not return anything apparently and there is no response as well as data. What am I missing?

Seems like I'm not sending anything back, but I'm not sure how to do it in this case.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const {MongoClient, ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
})



app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Connect success');
    const dbname = 'people';
    const db = client.db(dbname);
    db.collection('people').find().toArray()
    .then(response => response)
    .then(data => res.send(data));
  })
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Connect success');
    const dbname = 'people';
    const db = client.db(dbname);
    db.collection('people').insertOne(req.body, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Insertion success');
    })
})})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server has started on ${port}`);
})
```

You were right, I don't send anything that's why get nothing on fronted. I have figured out what I have missed, thank you.

The correct code is:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Connect success');
    const dbname = 'people';
    const db = client.db(dbname);
    const entry = req.body;
    db.collection('people').insertOne(entry, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Insertion success');
      res.send(entry);
    })
})})
```

Comment: Did you send anything as a response from the Backend? Can you post your backend code here please.

Comment: Hi, @ubaidshaikh, thanks for response, I have posted my full backend code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from your backend, hence fetch does not return anything and apparently you get no response. Try sending a response back like below

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }, (err, client) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('Connect success');
        const dbname = 'people';
        const db = client.db(dbname);
        db.collection('people').insertOne(req.body, (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Insertion success');
                console.log('inserted record', response.ops[0]);
                res.send(response.ops[0]);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Please try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: By the way, what do you want as a response??

Comment: No, it is not working, gives me - cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: I'd like to get object I'm inserting back to process it on frontend.